# Is there a way to calculate a star's luminosity from its apparent magnitude?

Tags: luminosity, apparent-magnitude

I was wondering if there's a way to calculate a star's luminosity from apparent magnitude data.

Comment: You see a distant light. You know it's a light bulb. Can you tell how many watts it has? You know what a 100W lamp looks from 1m distance What do you need to know to be able to determine the power or absolute brightness (=luminosity) of the distant lamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to know the distance to the star first (which you can get using the [distance ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder)). From there, you can infer the [luminosity distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_distance), and then use the flux you measure to calculate the luminosity using the flux-distance relationship.

Comment: This an incomplete answer, since in general, a broadband magnitude does not give you the bolometric flux.

Comment: @ProfRob you almost surely know more about this corner of astronomy than me, so you should write an answer =)